# MultipartFile upload test in Spring Boot Failing - not sure why

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-boot-test

I'm testing a POST method in a controller that handles the uploading of an image via a MultipartFile. It is allowed to be empty, but if there is a file present, it should upload it. I wrote a Unit test to make sure it worked, but the test is failing, returning a 404, and I'm not sure why - probably because I'm not adept at reading what's happening. Here's the test:

```
@Test
  public void saveAnEntryWhenPOSTNewUserWithAPicture() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile multiPFImage = new MockMultipartFile("ABCPicture", "abcpic.png",
            "img/png", "Generate bytes to simulate a picture".getBytes());
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/newcontact")
            .file(multiPFImage)
            .param("userId", "12345")
            .param("name", "Picture Uploader User"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("savedContact")));
  }
```

And here's the stack trace that results from running that test:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /newContact
       Parameters = {userId=[12345], name=[John Smith]}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = app.controllers.AdditiveController
           Method = public java.lang.String app.controllers.AdditiveController.createNewContact(app.models.dto.ContactDTO)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[text/plain;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[12]}
     Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             Body = savedContact
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /newContact
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = app.controllers.AdditiveController
           Method = public app.models.dto.ContactDTO app.controllers.AdditiveController.sendNewContactForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"userId":null,"contactId":null,"name":null,"email":null,"bday":null,"address":null,"city":null,"state":null,"phones":null,"contactImg":null}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /newcontact
       Parameters = {userId=[12345], name=[Picture Uploader User]}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8]}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:665)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at app.controllers.AdditiveControllerShould.saveAnEntryWhenPOSTNewUserWithAPicture(AdditiveControllerShould.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Edit:

Here is the controller method which is being tested:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/newContact")
  public String createNewContact(@ModelAttribute ContactDTO newContact) {
    Contact contact = new Contact(newContact.getUserId(), newContact.getName());
    setOptionalContactFields(contact, newContact);
    contactDAO.save(contact); // contactId automatically generated here (via SQL autoIncrement)
    newContact.setContactId(contact.getContactId()); // update the newContact to include the contactId
    if (newContact.getContactImg() !=null ) { 
      uploadContactProfileImg(newContact); // handles actual saving of image to persistence layer
    }

    return "savedContact"; // assumes template that can display all fields of a Contact will be returned
  }
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add the controller code?

Comment: @ChiDov yep! just added it now

Comment: did you add SpringBootTest or MvcWebTest annotation at the test class? please provide the full test class.

Comment: @ChiDov 
used SpringBootTest. I didn't want to clutter up the area above further. The full code for my Github for the class though can be found here: goo.gl/Mos4Vt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you have mistype `MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/newcontact")`

should be `MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/newContact")`

Additional:
There's a typo in your DTO

```
public class ContactDTO {
  private MultipartFile conactImg;
}
```

request multipart name should be the same with DTO, **ABCPicture** should be **conactImg**

Comment: Ahh, ok. That's amazing, thank you! Just for future readers they were:
1.)The "conact" typo. Corrected all instances of this to "contact". 2.) The `new MockMultipartFile("ABCPicture", "abcpic.png",
            "img/png", "Generate bytes to simulate a picture".getBytes())` needed to have its name match the DTO field's identifier name, so swapped `ABCPicture` for the corrected `contactImg` and lastly 3.) Since the controller had this: `@GetMapping(path = "/newContact")` , the path IS case-sensitive, so when I call it in the test, it needs to match. `fileUpload("/newContact")`